# Does bridging two network interfaces prevent web server access running on the host?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bridge, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi setup as a wireless bridge for an XBox (i.e. Ethernet bridged to the wifi). Currently I can plug in a keyboard directly to reconfigure. Since the bridging works at the lowest two OSI layers, is there no way of accessing a web server on the Pi? Will it automatically be forwarding all traffic to the wifi card straight to the XBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not prevent doing that. The bridge itself is still on the network, and it can have an IP address of its own.

Comment: hmm when I tried to ssh into the wlan0 address I got nothing, whereas when the bridge state is DOWN it was okay..

Comment: @CalvinFlegal: The *bridge* (`br0`) can have its own IP address – not the individual bridged interfaces.

Comment: or, rather, when the interfaces were not added to the bridge.

Comment: Would the bridge be the ip I would try to access to get to the web server, or the wlan0??